# When forwarding WebSocket requests through a load balancer, does the load balancer incur a significant overhead?

Tags: websocket, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, aws-application-load-balancer

I am currently developing a chat server and have encountered a question while deploying it in a cloud environment. I've designed the architecture based on a 3-tier structure. If a user sends a request to the load balancer using the HTTPS protocol, the load balancer redirects it to the web application server using HTTP. After the web application server responds, the load balancer redirects it back to the user using HTTPS.

My concern arises with the addition of the chat server to this structure. If the chat server is added to the load balancer's target group, WebSocket connections would be established not between the user and the chat server, but between the chat server and the load balancer. In that case, I anticipate a significant increase in traffic directed towards the load balancer. Is my understanding correct?

To summarize, I'm curious if, in the scenario of User <-> Load Balancer <-> Chat Server, WebSocket connections are established between the Load Balancer <-> Chat Server, and I'm also wondering if this results in a substantial increase in traffic on the load balancer.

I couldn't find answers to my questions even after searching the AWS documentations and a lot of blog...

Thank you for reading my question